# What is the best way to add custom methods into generated protoc classes for Python?

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

I'm using protobuf 3.2 and Python 3.5
My model:

```
message MyMessage {
    string field_1 = 1;
    string field_2 = 2;
}
```

protoc generates me a file with done classes.
My aim is to add some custom methods and (if it possible) some fields.

For example add this:

```
def get_full_message(self):
    return self.field_1 + " " + self.field_2

def __repr__(self):
   return self.field_1 + "/" + self.field_2
```

What is the best way to do this? 
There is note in the documentation that inheritance is bad for such generated classes. Also another way is Monkey Patching but I'm not sure that it will work right.
Thanks!

Comment: I rather feel inheritance is a nice solution. What doc told you to not inherit?

Comment: @TatsuyukiIshi there is https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/pythontutorial ."Don't go looking for facilities similar to class inheritance, though – protocol buffers don't do that."

Comment: I suggest you to do a composition, by taking the protobuf class as a field.

Comment: @TatsuyukiIshi thx! Actually now I have the same opinion.